# Refreshing the row and replacing the two columns of a row with the responsegot from action class

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I have table in jsp page and refresh button on each row,and onclick of each refresh button i have a javascript/ajax call ,in which it will go to action class and get the values of status and #records and replace the columns with retrieved data of corresponding row

This is my jsp table:

```
<table border="1" class="displaytab" id="rtable">
         <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">
         <tr>   <td  colspan="10" style="background:#7395B8;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;"><center>Admin</center></td></tr>
         </s:if>
         <tr> 
         <th>FileId</th><th>File Name</th><th>Upload Date</th><th>#Records</th><th>Status</th><th>Estimated Time</th><th>Processed Records</th><th>Generate Report</th><th></th><s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}"><th>Controls</th></s:if>
         </tr>

         <s:iterator value="uploadList" var="m"> 
            <tr>   
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" /></td> 
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileName}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.uploadDate}" /></td>
            <td><div id="div2"><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></div></td>
            <td><div id="div1"><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></div></td>
            <td>tbd</td>

            <td><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/generate.png" title="Generate Report"></a></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" id="refresh" onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" />);"></a></td>
```

this is my javascript with ajax:

```
var id;
         function refreshRecord(value)
        {
            id = value;
            alert(id);
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#refresh").click(function(){
               var fileId=id;
               alert("ajax id is "+fileId);
               var rowNum = $(this).parent().parent().index();;
               alert(rowNum);
               $.ajax({
               type:"post",
                url:"checkStatusAndNumRecs",
               data:{fileId:fileId},
                success:function(data)
               {
                    setTimeout(alert(data), 2000);
                    var allTds = $("#rtable tr:eq('"+rowNum+"')").find('td');
                    $(allTds)[4].html(data[0]);               
                    $(allTds)[3].html(data[1]);
               },
               error:function(data)
               {
                $("#div1").html("It was a failure !!!");
               }
                });
                });
                });
        </script>
```

this is my action class "checkStatusAndNumRecs"
public String execute()
    {

```
    System.out.println("here inside action-------------");
    PersistenceService svc = PersistenceServiceImpl.getInstance();
    status = svc.getStatusByFileId(fileId);
    System.out.println("status is "+status);
    numRecords = svc.getNumRecordsByFileId(fileId);
    System.out.println("num records are "+numRecords);
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

I am running this,in action class i am getting status and numRecords,
problem is

1. only for first row ajax function is calling,remaining rows its not going inside the ajax function
2. I am not getting the status and numRecords in ajax

3.datafrom action class should replace with the two columns status and #records.
please can any body help,i am struggling for this from couple of days.

and i am not using servlet,and in table i am iterating the list for the data.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter problem like that,I think your problem is in your html table.You placed your refresh button in your table.When ajax come to your refresh button it can't read button and an exception occur than it doesn't pass next row.